Connection .NET backend to React using cors
import axios from 'axios';

const Registration = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    userName: '',
    userEmail: '',
    userPhoneNumber: '',
    userAddress: '',
    userAge: 0, // Initialize with a number
    userGender: '',
  });

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const data = {
        ...formData,
      };

      const response = await axios.post('https://localhost:7094/api/User/Create', data);
      const responseData = await response.json();

      console.log('Response data:', responseData);

      // Handle successful response (potentially redirect to login or display a success message)
      // You may receive the generated userId and password in the responseData
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('There was an error!', error);
      setError(error.message);
      // Handle error response
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {error && <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</div>}
      <div>
        <label>UserName:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userName" value={formData.userName} onChange={handleChange} required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="userEmail" value={formData.userEmail} onChange={handleChange} required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userPhoneNumber" value={formData.userPhoneNumber} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userAddress" value={formData.userAddress} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input type="number" name="userAge" value={formData.userAge} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Gender:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userGender" value={formData.userGender} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Role (for display only):</label>
        <input type="text" name="role" value={formData.role} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Registration;

Above is my react file

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Text;
using TrainTicket.Interfaces;
using TrainTicket.Models;
using TrainTicket.Repository;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//applying cors

var corsOrigins = new string[] { "http://localhost:5173" };

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(corsOrigins)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ReservationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

/// Adding interface and repositories for their usage in whole appliction
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserLoginInterface, UserLoginRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserInterface, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAdminLoginInterface, AdminLoginRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITrainDetailsInterface, TrainDetailsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISeatDetailsInterface, SeatDetailsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISearchDetailsInterface, SearchDetailsRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderInterface, EmailSenderRepository>();

// Add Jwt services to the system
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero ///Token is invalidated immediately after its expiration time
    };
});

//Add services for Swagger
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "TrainTicket API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        Scheme = "bearer"
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();
//using cors
app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseAuthentication();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "TrainTicket API v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Above is .NET program.cs file.
I have tried multiple ways of cors enabling but it did not.
I have tried using axios and without axios still no effect.
The registration page needs - userName , userEmail , PhoneNumber, Adress , Age, Gender , Role(user or admin)- for authentication.  [userId and password are auto generated]
The submit button when clicked values are not showing up on my database.

CORS headers are configured on the backend. You can't do anything to CORS on the axios side.

You shouldn't do "AllowAll" for CORS. CORS exists not without a reason. You should allow only specific domain.

Why do you think it has anything to do with CORS? Error messages says "Network error".

Hi whizzx, I can't find the cors issue from your screenshot, I guess the issue is related vite settings, so please share the vite.config.js, thanks.

if the controller requires credentials you need to configure axios to send them with each request { withCredentials: true }, I noticed it is set to false in your screenshot, but I also noticed its the registration page and maybe you've put the registration controller behind auth by accident?

Please also share the screenshot of network trace (From Browser Developer Tools), we need to check the error code, 401 or others.
